# Method is not called once uncheck all is clicked

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need your assistant in calling a method once the user clicks on the Unselect All checkbox which is located at the top of the dataTable. The dataTable code is:

```
<p:dataTable id="PendingRequests" var="hr" selection="#{hrdirector.selectedRequests}"
             value="#{hrd.listPendingRequests}"  rowKey="#{hr.requestNo}"
             paginatorTemplate="{RowsPerPageDropdown} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15" paginatorPosition="bottom"
             filteredValue="#{hrd.filteredRequests}" widgetVar="dataTableWidgetVar"
             emptyMessage="No Requests are available to be displayed">
             <p:ajax event="toggleSelect" listener="#{hrdirector.ShowTotalSelectAll}" process="@this"
                                update="@form"/>
```

And the code in the method ShowTotalSelectAll is:

```
public void ShowTotalSelectAll() {
if (selectedRequests.size() > 0 || selectedRequests != null)
{
// do some actions
else {
System.out.println("UnSelect All");
```

// update total
    }
    }
The above code will work only in case of the Select All, however when the user clicks again to Unselect, the method will not be called.

Comment: `selectedRequests.size() > 0 || selectedRequests != null` a bit late to check for null, when you already dereferenced it by calling size(). `if (selectedRequests.size() > 0) ... else{ selectedRequests.clear();` - so if empty then clear? This is a mess.

Comment: ... a mess and a potential NPE, since one of conditions to enter a clearing block is `selected == null`.

Comment: @Vsevolod Golovanov @ M. Prokhorov post editted

Comment: So it works when you not have an `emptymessage`? Or not using filtering? Please create a [mcve]